# Maxwell equations in 2+1 D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differential-geometry, maxwell-equations, conventions

I have a problem with the Maxwell equations in (2+1) dimensions using differential form. Following J. Baez "Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity" page 93 (or any other book), the equations are

\begin{align}dF &=0\\
*d*F &=J
\end{align}

with $J=-\rho dt+j$ which is a 1-form, and $F$ is the electromagnetic tensor field (2-form).
These equations give the correct Maxwell equations in (3+1) dimension but in (2+1) there is a different equation with a minus sign

\begin{align}\text{div} \;E=-\rho.
\end{align}

To detail the things
\begin{align}
F &=B dx\wedge dy-E_x dt\wedge dx-E_y dt \wedge dy\\
*F &=B dt+E_x dy-E_y dx\\
d*F &= -(\partial_t E_y-\partial_x B) dt\wedge dx+(\partial_t E_x-\partial_y B) dt\wedge dy+(\partial_x E_x+\partial_y E_y) dx\wedge dy\\
*d*F &= (\partial_x E_x+\partial_y E_y) dt+(\partial_t E_x-\partial_y B) dx+(\partial_t E_y-\partial_x B) dy
\end{align}

which implies

\begin{align}\text{div} \;E=-\rho.
\end{align}

WHY, there is a negative sign?

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with your sign permutations in the Hodge star operator calculation. If

$F = B + E \wedge dt$,

then, in 2D,

$F = B dx \wedge dy + E_x dx \wedge dt + E_y dy \wedge dt$,

as you wrote yourself. Now, let us take our initial Hodge star as $\star dx \wedge dy = dt$. This means that $\star dt \wedge dx = dy$ and $\star dy \wedge dt = dx$, by cyclic permutation (right hand rule, and here's your mistake, I think). This means that

$\star F = B dt - E_x dy + E_y dx$,

which disagrees in sign to what you got. Indeed, it is easy to see that

$(\star d \star F)(\partial_t) = - (\partial_x E_x + \partial_y E_y) $ ,

which fixes the sign implying $\nabla \cdot E = \rho$.

Comment: The formula for the hodge operator I have is $*dx\wedge dt=\epsilon^{10}_{~~~~~2}dy=-\epsilon_{102}dy=dy$. This is why, I'm getting $+E_x dy$

Comment: Well, if you want $\star dx \wedge dt = dy$, then you must necessarily have $\star dy \wedge dx = dt$ (sign change) and $\star dt \wedge dy = dx$, which fixes your sign yet again. You're using wrong Hodge duals in analyzing $\star d \star F$.

Comment: Thx. If you have the Nakahara (Geometry, Topology and physics), could you please tell me if his formula 7.172 is incorrect, because this is the one I'm using

Comment: No, Nakahara is not incorrect. It's just complicating something very simple. The Wikipedia article for the Hodge dual is much better than Nakahara's, in my opinion. I think you are probably doing something wrong with your signs when using Nakahara's formula, that's all

Comment: @anubis If I didn't answer your question please tell me and I will elaborate even more. If I did, and I think this is the case, please set my post as an answer so that this matter can be closed.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't answer before. Could you please elaborate more about the formula used by Nakahara, because the idea for me, is to use these calculations in curved spacetime and I need to use some formula. What I don't understand is that the formula that he wrote works in 4D but not in 3D while he says that it is correct for any D. And it is pretty straightforward formula so it doesn't look like if I mixed up some indices

Comment: The answer to this can be found in the previously mentioned Wikipedia article. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#Index_notation_for_the_star_operator

Comment: I agree that this formula works. But you said "Nakahara is not incorrect". They can't be both correct. So let me ask again. Is Nakahara's formula incorrect ?

Comment: Finally, I think I have my answer. The fundamental equation should be $d*F=*J$ and not $*d*F=J$ which in 4D for a Lorentzian manifold gives $*d*F=J$ because $*^2=1$ but in 3D $*^2=-1$ for Lorentzian signature, which implies that we have $*d*F=-J$.
Because I see know that even the last equation was not correct, we need $-\partial_t E + ... = j$

Comment: I'm glad you made it =)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, and the book is wrong. Its $J$ has the wrong sign.

Bear in mind, this is a monograph, not a peer-reviewed article. Monographs of any level of complexity are *extremely* prone to and laden with errors. For example,

**Exact Solutions Of Einstein's Field Equations**
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/exact-solutions-of-einsteins-field-equations/11CF6CFCC10CC62B9B299F08C32C37A6

writes down the wrong definition for the Riemann Curvature Tensor (!!) and totally mangles up the definition of Lie derivatives. In

**Gravitation: Foundations and Frontiers**
[https://www.amazon.com/Gravitation-Foundations-Frontiers-T-Padmanabhan/dp/0521882230](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521882230)

most of the equations in Chapter 1 are mangled up and wrong; and the book you're citing

**Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity (Knots and Everything)**
[https://www.amazon.com/GAUGE-FIELDS-KNOTS-GRAVITY-Everything/dp/9810220340](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9810220340)

is filled with errors! That's one of them.

That's only the tip of the iceberg, there are a whole lot of more examples like that.

In part, this is because books like these were written before the publishing technology, like TeX, became as accessible and easy to use as it is today; making writing as transparent and computer-powered as it is today. TeX, itself, was a lot harder to use, too.

So, basically you were stuck in the slow lane on paper or (worse) a chalkboard, and that alone creates enough of a distraction to causes errors to crop up. Nowadays, with a good editor and (even) automation, a lot of the grunge work - and the distraction that comes with it - can go away. Part of "computer-powered" also means that it's *much* easier to correct the errors when they are found and easier to do a run-through to find them. If you weren't around when people used typewriters, then you don't know how good you have it today.

So, let's do this carefully and rigorously.

The potential one form in the coordinates $\left(x^0, x^1, x^2\right) = (t, x, y)$ is:
$$A_μ dx^μ = A_x dx + A_y dy - φ dt.$$
The field strength two-form, given by, component-wise, by $F_{μν} = ∂_μ A_ν - ∂_ν A_μ$ is:
$$F = ½ F_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν = B dx dy + \left(E_x dx + E_y dy\right) dt.$$
In here and the following, I will be denoting wedge products by juxtaposition, and ordinary products of coordinate differentials will stand for wedge products - *except* for the metric line element, which I'll only mention and use twice below. The field strength components satisfy the equations:
$$B = \frac{∂A_y}{∂x} - \frac{∂A_x}{∂y}, \hspace 1em
E_x = -\frac{∂A_x}{∂t} - \frac{∂φ}{∂x}, \hspace 1em
E_y = -\frac{∂A_y}{∂t} - \frac{∂φ}{∂y}, \hspace 1em
\frac{∂B}{∂t} = \frac{∂E_x}{∂y} - \frac{∂E_y}{∂x}.
$$

So, the first thing we note is that, unlike 4-dimensions, there is a scale-dependency on the metric in the formula for the Lagrangian density:
$$ = -¼ k \sqrt{|g|} g^{μρ} g^{νσ} F_{μρ} F_{νσ}.$$
If you adopt a metric with the line element
$$g_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν = β dt^2 - α \left(dx^2 + dy^2\right), \hspace 1em β = α c^2,$$
with coordinates $\left(x^0, x^1, x^2\right) = (t, x, y)$, then you will need to set $k = ε_0 c \sqrt{|α|}$ to get the correct Lagrangian density
$$ = ½ \left(ε_0\left({E_x}^2 + {E_y}^2\right) - \frac{B^2}{μ_0}\right), \hspace 1em μ_0 = \frac{1}{ε_0c^2}.$$

So, the natural scaling for the metric is with $|α| = 1$. The sign of $α$ will have no bearing on anything, so we make this a line element for proper distance, with $α = -1$ and $β = -c^2$:
$$g_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν = dx^2 + dy^2 - c^2 dt^2.$$

Second, we will then have
$$d^3x = dt dx dy, \hspace 1em \sqrt{|g|} d^3x = c dt dx dy.$$

The Hodge Dual is defined in terms of the contraction operator $(\_)˩(\_)$ and metric by:
$$\star{\left(dx^μ⋯dx^ν\right)} = ∂^ν ˩ ⋯ ∂^μ ˩ \sqrt{|g|} d^3 x$$
Thus
$$
\star{(dx dy)} = ∂^y ˩ ∂^x ˩ c dt dx dy = c ∂_y ˩ ∂_x ˩ dt dx dy = -c ∂_y ˩ dt dy = c dt, \\
\star{(dx dt)} = ∂^t ˩ ∂^x ˩ c dt dx dy = -\frac{∂_t ˩ ∂_x ˩ dt dx dy}{c} = \frac{∂_t ˩ dt dy}{c} = \frac{dy}{c}, \\
\star{(dy dt)} = ∂^t ˩ ∂^y ˩ c dt dx dy = -\frac{∂_t ˩ ∂_y ˩ dt dx dy}{c} = -\frac{∂_t ˩ dt dx}{c} = -\frac{dx}{c}. \\
$$

The components of the response fields $^x$, $^y$, $ℌ$ and source $^x$, $^y$, $ρ$ are of tensor *densities* (hint: the names "charge *density*", "current *density*"), defined in terms of the Lagrangian density by
$$
^x = \frac{∂}{∂E_x}, \hspace 1em ^y = \frac{∂}{∂E_y}, \hspace 1em ℌ = -\frac{∂}{∂B}, \\
^x = \frac{∂}{∂A_x}, \hspace 1em ^y = \frac{∂}{∂A_y}, \hspace 1em ρ = -\frac{∂}{∂φ}.
$$
Then, from the total variational
$$\begin{align}
Δ &= ΔE_x ^x + ΔE_y ^y - ΔB ℌ + ΔA_x ^x + ΔA_y ^y - Δφ ρ \\
&= -\frac{∂}{∂t} \left(ΔA_x ^x + ΔA_y ^y\right) - \frac{∂}{∂x} \left(ΔA_y ℌ + Δφ ^x\right) + \frac{∂}{∂y} \left(ΔA_x ℌ - Δφ ^y\right) \\
&+ Δφ \left(\frac{∂^x}{∂x} + \frac{∂^y}{∂y} - ρ\right) + ΔA_x \left(^x + \frac{∂^x}{∂t} - \frac{∂ℌ}{∂y}\right) + ΔA_y \left(^y + \frac{∂^y}{∂t} + \frac{∂ℌ}{∂x}\right),
\end{align}$$
the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations and (resulting) continuity equation can then be read off:
$$
\frac{∂^x}{∂x} + \frac{∂^y}{∂y} = ρ, \hspace 1em
\frac{∂ℌ}{∂y} - \frac{∂^x}{∂t} = ^x, \hspace 1em
-\frac{∂ℌ}{∂x} - \frac{∂^y}{∂t} = ^y, \hspace 1em
\frac{∂ρ}{∂t} + \frac{∂^x}{∂x} + \frac{∂^y}{∂y} = 0.
$$

In terms of differential forms, the variational of the Lagrangian 3-form $L =  d^3x$ can be written as:
$$ΔL = (ΔA)J - (ΔF)G = d(-(ΔA)G) + (ΔA)(J - dG),$$
and the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation and continuity equation as:
$$dG = J, \hspace 1em dJ = 0,$$
provided we set:
$$G = ℌ dt + ^x dy - ^y dx, \hspace 1em J = ρ dx dy + \left(^x dy - ^y dx\right) dt.$$

From the Lagrangian density, as originally stated, we can directly read off the constitutive relations between the field strengths and response fields:
$$B = μ_0 ℌ, \hspace 1em ^x = ε_0 E_x, \hspace 1em ^y = ε_0 E_y.$$
Upon substitution into $G$, we get:
$$\begin{align}
G &= \frac{B}{μ_0} dt + ε_0 \left(E_x dy - E_y dx\right) \\
&= ε_0 c \left(B cdt + E_x \frac{dy}{c} - E_y \frac{dx}{c}\right) \\
&= ε_0 c \left(B \star{(dx dy)} + E_x \star{(dx dt)} + E_y \star{(dy dt)}\right) \\
&= ε_0 c \star{F}.
\end{align}$$

By virtue of $J = dG$, my $J$ is your $ε_0 c d\star{F}$. Therefore, by virtue of your equation $\star{d\star{F}} = J$, my $\star{J}$ is your $ε_0 c J$. Taking the Hodge-dual of my $J$ results in:
$$\begin{align}
\star{J} &= ρ \star{(dx dy)} + ^x \star{(dy dt)} - ^y \star{(dx dt)} \\
&= ρ c dt - ^x \frac{dx}{c} - ^y \frac{dy}{c} \\
&= ρ c dt - \frac{^x dx + ^y dy}{c}.
\end{align}$$
Therefore, your $J$, in component form, is:
$$\frac{ρ}{ε_0} dt - μ_0 \left(^x dx + ^y dy\right).$$